# Plex how to get the claim token with CLI

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command-line-interface, plex

I'm getting issue when I try to claim the token throught cli. In the normal way you access https://www.plex.tv/claim/ and get the token, if not logged you'll need to log in with your account. I'm wondering it it's possible to get the claim token giving the `username` and `password`.

First, I need to log in and get the auth token. I have made this command in cURL :

```
curl -X "POST" "https://plex.tv/users/sign_in.json" -H "X-Plex-Version: 1.0.0" -H "X-Plex-Product: WHATEVER" -H "X-Plex-Client-Identifier: YOUR-PRODUCT-ID" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" --data-urlencode "user[password]=PASSWORD" --data-urlencode "user[login]=LOGIN-OR-EMAIL"
```

It output something like :

```
{  
   "user":{  
      "id":234612345,
      "uuid":"c59ae6a4785ea41",
      "email":"mail@domain",
      "joined_at":"2019-01-13T14:20:05.000Z",
      "username":"userA",
      "title":"userA",
      "thumb":"https://plex.tv/users/c19ae7c44546aa41/avatar?c=1557225551",
      "hasPassword":true,
      "authToken":"ysdfzerk47qnCSm7zYqzEAZIds4VF3b",
      "authentication_token":"ysdfzerk47qnCSm7zYqzEAZIds4VF3b",
      "subscription":{  
         "active":false,
         "status":"Inactive",
         "plan":null,
         "features":[  
            "adaptive_bitrate",
            "collections",
            "photos-metadata-edition",
            "radio",
            "photos-favorites",
            "federated-auth",
            "Android - PiP",
            "publishing_platform",
            "news",
            "kevin-bacon",
            "client-radio-stations",
            "TREBLE-show-features",
            "web_server_dashboard",
            "conan_redirect_qa",
            "conan_redirect_alpha",
            "conan_redirect_beta",
            "conan_redirect_public",
            "news_local_now",
            "transcoder_cache",
            "artist-tv"
         ]
      },
      "roles":{  
         "roles":[  

         ]
      },
      "entitlements":[  

      ],
      "confirmedAt":null,
      "forumId":null,
      "rememberMe":false
   }
}
```

How can I claim the token now ? I don't found any api to get that token. We can only get from the website https://www.plex.tv/claim/

The token is like : claim-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I can't find the token in the source page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it looking at source of plex. Here is a sample script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Token: <span id="token"></span></span>
<script>
var TokenIdentifier = ""
var ClientIdentifier = ""
var i = {
    "X-Plex-Product": "Plex SSO",
    "X-Plex-Token": TokenIdentifier,
    "X-Plex-Client-Identifier": ClientIdentifier 
};
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    headers: i,
    url: "https://plex.tv/api/claim/token.json",
    crossDomain: !0,
    success: function(e) {
        $.each(e, function(index, element) {
            document.getElementById("token").innerHTML = element;
        });
    }
})
</script>
```